# Computing the limit.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits, functions

Studying for a midterm.

Compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{x+4}{x^2+3x-4}$$

Factor the denominator:

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{x+4}{(x+4)(x-1)}$$

The $(x+4)s$ cancel out:

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac1{(x-1)}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac1{(4-1)}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 4}=\frac13$$

Just wondering if somebody could verify if my answer is correct, as there is no answer key.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Why did the denominator become the numerator?

Comment: @Unknow, by any chance, it is $x\to-4?$

Comment: If it really is supposed to be $x\to 4$, you can just plug in $x=4$ at the beginning.  Always check first if you can just use continuity.

Comment: Andre is right, you don't always have to factor if plugging it in gets the right answer. It's good that you have that technique in mind but if there is a simpler solution, it's mostly likely better.

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually plugged it in right after I posted the question, so I figured something was up. I guess I just assumed my prof wouldn't have a question that was that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is nearly correct; you switch the denominator to the numerator. The correct answer should be $1/3$.

Comment: Thanks, I knew something was up when I inputted 4 into the original equation and came to $1/3$ or$0.333$. For some reason I thought when you cancel out the two $x-4$ they just disappeared into space, thanks for your help.